# Suspicious incoming connection attempts from random IPv6 addresses on local network on macOS

Tags: network, malware, macos, ipv6

I've been using Little Snitch on my Macbook and I have since a long time a rule to alert on any incoming IPv6 connection, which would be suspicious since I use IPv4 only.

Since a couple of days I've been getting regular alerts for incoming connections like this one:

[image: Little Snitch connection alert]

When I deny the connection another alert pops up for another IPv6 address (doesn't matter if I choose once, forever, until logout, for 7 days, etc). When I open Little Snitch to look at the rules it created, each rule has a different address. Obviously I haven't tried what happens when I allow the connection.

Each time when an alert pops up, it's either `rapportd` that wants to accept the connection on port `49152` or `sharingd` on port `8770`.

I have no experience with IPv6 though and have no clue where to begin to investigate beyond some basics I could think of:

- Run a scan with both MalwareBytes and KnockKnock (takes inventory of what's persistently installed on macOS and checks each item with VirusTotal): no malware found
- find the device from which the connection originates: [IPv6 neighbor discovery](https://www.itdojo.com/know-thy-ipv6-neighbor/) shows no neighbors, also not when tried from a RPi connected to the same subnet.
- try to rule out that connections are coming from my iPhone, since these are both apple services: alerts keep coming when I disconnect my iPhone from wifi. Just in case I also disabled bluetooth, which makes no difference
- disable my macbook's Wifi adapter and see what happens: no more connection alerts

I'm running macOS Big Sur with all the latest updates.

**Question**

Any idea what this might be? I'm wondering if my machine and/or another device on my network has possibly been compromised.

What is the recommended approach for investigating a case like this?

Comment: Did you try using `ndp` to resolve that specific address (i.e. `ndp fe80:9::301e:...`), or try pinging it (`ping6 fe80:9::301e:...`) and *then* trying `ndp -na`? The other thing that comes to mind is running a packet capture (something like `sudo tcpdump -en -i en0 ip6 and tcp and ip6[53]&2!=0 and (port 49152 or 8770)'`, although you may have to replace `en0` with whatever interface the connections are coming from). In either case, if you can find the hardware address it's coming from that'll give you a handle to track it down.

Comment: Thanks, that got me a bit closer; `ndp -na` output indeed includes an entry after executing `ndp` against that specific address; Interesting parts of the output are: 1) `Linklayer Address = (Incomplete)` i.e. no Mac Address, 2) `Netif = awdl0` which apparently is an [Apple Wireless Direct Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28196009/741217) interface, 3) `Neighbor Cache State = Nostate` which I assume is related to it not showing up initially. So still no origin unfortunately.

Comment: I tried using an [IPv6 address calculator](http://silmor.de/ipaddrcalc.html#ip6) but no dice there either. Not sure what this implies, perhaps that it's not really link-local or auto-configure, but I guess it makes sense that it doesn't resolve to a mac address since AFAIK a MAC address should map to a single address and the origin address is different each time.

Comment: I've been away from my computer for a couple of days and there were a few more Little Snitch alerts while I was gone, but none since I started using my computer again. So last origin address couldn't be reached by ping and there is no traffic captured when running `sudo tcpdump -en -i awdl0 ip6 and tcp and ip6[53]\&2!=0 and \(port 49152 or 8770\)` (had to escape some chars). I'll keep it running in the background for when it happens again. What does the `ip6[53]&2!=0` part of the filter expression mean?

Comment: So I learned some interesting things but not much wiser because I don't what any of this means for this issue. Does this give you important clues already?

Comment: I'm on the same boat and haven't found a clear answer, so decided to turn IPv6 off in my WiFi adapter in my mac